# Value missing in IIS7/Classic ASP

Tags: sql-server, iis-7, asp-classic

I have a development server and a live server. Both are Windows Server 2008 running IIS7 and SQL Server. I have identical databases on both which I'm accessing using Classic ASP.

On my development server, everything works fine and I can create a recordset with all of the data as expected. On my live server exactly the same is true, except that in the recordset being returned, one of the field values (i.e. one of the columns) is empty. I've run a query on the server in SQL Server and the data is definitely there, but the ASP page is not fetching it.

Given that everything is pretty much identical on the two servers and one works and one doesn't, it looks like it might be the way Classic ASP is set up on IIS7. The field value that's not being returned is a varchar(MAX) with maybe 100 characters. Is there anything in Classic ASP on IIS7 that could prevent this data from being returned to the ASP page?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is your connection string?

From [this link](http://johnrpattison.com/2008/08/29/problem-accessing-varcharmax-field-from-classic-asp/), it looks like certain older providers, like `SQLNCLI`, have issues.  Try `SQLOLEDB` or `SQLNCLI10`.

More info from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130978.aspx).

Comment: That looks really interesting. I can't check it on the live machine today but I'll certainly take a look at it tomorrow. Thanks.

Comment: Changing the connection string to SQLNCLI10 solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Is the result coming from a string concatenation ?

Perhaps the development server has [`CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259202%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) set to `OFF` and the live to `ON`.

(*this is a SQL Server setting and not an IIS one..*)

Comment: I'm not sure, but I don't think it could be that. When I run the query on SQL Server it shows the data as it should be, so I wouldn't have thought it could be a SQL Server setting. The problem only occurs when I try and fetch this data using ASP.